# Selection member methods

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to write code that:

1. Finds/locates specific strings that appear in the first column of tables in a Word document.
2. Maps these strings to the immediate headings of the tables that they appear in.
3. List out the string-heading mappings in an Excel spreadsheet.
   Caveat: All of the strings the VBA code will look for are listed under an existing Excel spreadsheet.

So far, I have been able to figure out #1 and #3 fairly easily. I figured #2 will need to use of the Selection class. I have been trying to familiarize myself with it but I am having a lot of trouble. For example, I have written a simple subroutine that resets the selection cursor to the beginning of a word document. This sub is called from a main sub in an Excel VBA.

```
Private Sub FindHeadings()
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:/Users/c11145/Desktop/SSDD_Trace/Test3.docx")

    'wrdDoc.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
End Sub
```

I am getting Run-time error "438": Object doesn't support this property or method.

I have also tried:

```
Dim sel As Selection
sel.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
```

But I get Run-time error 91.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to qualify your `Selection` because that is an available class in Excel, too.

I am pretty sure that whenever a classname may be shared by multiple libraries, the shortest reference (i.e., the active application's) is the default, so unless you qualify `Selection` will always refer to the Excel selection (shape, cell/range, etc.)

When I run something very simple in Word (not from Excel), I think this does what you need:

```
Sub test()
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

Set wrdDoc = ActiveDocument
Set wrdApp = wrdDoc.Parent

wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

End Sub
```

Porting this over to Excel, try qualifying `Selection` as a member of the `wrdApp`:

```
wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
```

The reason I use `6` instead of the enumerated constant `wdStory` is because the latter will fail unless you are using early binding with explicit reference to the Word object model.  If you are not doing early binding, then `wdStory` is essentially an undeclared variable with an `empty` value, which will raise a "Bad Parameter" errror on that line.